# about QSqlTableModel::setFilter

Tags: qt

about QSqlTableModel::setFilter
there is very few examples for QSqlTableModel::setFilter, and I try many way to use it but all failed:
//QString sqlstringqqq = QString("select * from alarmInfoTable where 1=1 order by rowid asc limit %1,20;").arg(beginIDqqq);
//QString sqlstringqqq = QString("select * from alarmInfoTable where 1=1 limit %1,20;").arg(beginIDqqq);

```
//QString sqlstringqqq = QString("SELECT * FROM alarmInfoTable LIMIT 3,10;");
//QString sqlstringqqq = QString("SELECT * FROM alarmInfoTable LIMIT 3,10");
QString sqlstringqqq = QString("select * from alarmInfoTable");


//ptableModel->setFilter("1=1 limit 2,10;");
//ptableModel->setFilter("limit 2,10;");

//ptableModel->setFilter("1=1 ORDER BY msgID ASC");
```

// ptableModel->setFilter("1=1 limit 3,7;");
ptableModel->setFilter("msgID>30;");

```
qDebug()<<" filter: "<< ptableModel->filter();


//ptableModel->setFilter(sqlstringqqq);
ptableModel->select();
```

is this method OK or not?
is there any examples can run for it?

Answer (score 1):

In `setFilter()` you can use **only** `WHERE` clause and only one filter at a time, so put all your filters into one string or use `QSortFilterProxyModel` subclass.

Example for `setFilter()`:

```
void YourModel::acceptFilter(const QString &value, bool useFilterByDate, bool useDogFilter)
{
    QString whereStr = "col_name = %1";
    
    if(useFilterByDate)
        whereStr += " AND DATE(date_col_name) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-06-06'";
    if(useDogFilter)
        whereStr += " AND col_name2 = 'dog'";

    setFilter(whereStr.arg(value));
}
```

If you want to use `LIMIT` you must override `selectStatement()` and append to query string your limit like so:

```
QString selectStatement() const
{
    QString qStr = QSqlTableModel::selectStatement();
    qStr += " LIMIT 100";
    return qStr;
}
```